# Delphi XE2 DataSnap – Random keys for the PC1 Filters

Tags: delphi, encryption, delphi-xe2, datasnap

Setting up a datasnap filters as described in the user manual will result in the RSA and PC1 filters having a fixed keys.

**What is the best way to generate a different random PC1 key for each session?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`PC1DynamicKey`](http://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/radstudiodemos/branches/RadStudio_XE2/Delphi/DataSnap/Authorization/PC1DynamicKey.pas?revision=381&view=markup) in the `AuthServerProject` sample.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/DataSnap.Role_Authorization_Sample